# What exactly is "integration" and why do services like Travis-CI exist?

Tags: continuous-integration, integration, travis-ci

I always see .travis-yml files in github repositories so I decided to google what they were used for. I found Travis-CI and and I've been reading, trying to understand what integration really is, but without an example, it's still just a general vague term to me. When do developers utilize integration and what exactly happens during integration? How does integration differ from continuous integration?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integration**, in Software Engineering, is the action of merging code from different developers (or for instance, from different **modules** of the same whole project) while trying to avoid errors in the process. It tries to make sure all the *pieces of code* that are not being made in the same place, by the same person, or that don't belong to the same *main* portion of the software, can interact without problems.

Talking about **Travis-CI**, there's a concept called **Continuous Integration** (as referred by @Simeon Visser) in the comments, that focuses on integrating the code in fixed periods of time (maybe once a day, or once every 12 hours for example) to assure the integrity of the *whole* system as it is being developed.